# Pointer arithmetic segmentation issue

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pointer-arithmetic

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int string_cmp(const void *p, const void *q);

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    int i;   // variable
    char **words_array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(argc+1)); // sets new array to hold the words
    char *p; // another char pointer array
    p = *words_array;       // set both equal to eachother

    for(; *p < (argc - 1); p++) // for loop
    {
            p = malloc(strlen(*argv) + 1); // determines size based on user input
            argv++; // increments
            strcpy(p++, *argv); // copies words to the new array

    }
    p = NULL; // resets p

    qsort(words_array, argc-1, sizeof(char *), string_cmp); // sorts the array
    for(i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++){ // for loop to print properly
            printf("%s ", words_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
  }

 int string_cmp (const void *p, const void *q) // compares the two different          strings and returns a value
{
    const char *value = *(const char**)p;
    const char *value_two = *(const char**)q;

    return strcmp(value, value_two);
}
```

So my program is supposed to take in command-line arguments and return them sorted using Qsort. Example would be "./a.out hello darkness my old friend should be returned as darkness friend hello my old. I don't get any compiler errors but instead I get a segmentation fault and I'm not sure how to fix this with my pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `p = *words_array;` Where is malloc for `words_array`?

Comment: Why are you declaring words_array as a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @sjsam malloc is right there when **words_array is declared

Comment: @RamblinRose and is there an easier way or how do i fix that?

Comment: Undefined behavior using the value of an object while it is indeterminate.

Answer (score -1):

you are incrementing double pointer(argv) i.e;

```
for(; *p < (argc - 1); p++) // for loop
{
        p = malloc(strlen(*argv) + 1); // determines size based on user input
        argv++; // increments
        strcpy(p++, *argv); // copies words to the new array

}
```

so change it to (*argv)++

Comment: Still getting the segmentation fault

Answer (score -1):

These are kinda suggestions :

change `char** argv` to `char* argv[]`

`argc` returns the one more than the actual number of arguments passed. The extra count is for the executable name itself.

So it is good to do some error checking, Do :

```
argc--;
if(argc > 0) // We have some arguments
{
/* Do something 
 * char **words_array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(argc+1)
 * may be changed to 
 */
  char **words_array;
  words_array=malloc(argc*sizeof(char*));
/* Coming down 
 * You could change that for-loop to something like this.
 */
 for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
     words_array[i]=argv[i]; //  You have all the arguments stored in words_array
/* Now go on sort words_array
 * and so and so forth
 */    

}
```

Comment: Why do you decrement the argc at the beginning?

Comment: Supporse you do `./your_program_name Romeo Juliet` then argc returns 3. `argc` counts `your_program_name` also. So I decremented it in the beginning to make it equal to actual number of parameters you passed.

Comment: okay one more question is I have char **words_array equal to malloc and all that should I not be using double **? or Is there a reason you just used one?

Comment: Also I changed the code to try that but now it says that the words_array in my qsort is undeclared? I don't understand what changed

Comment: Suppose you have char* c and you wish to allocate some memory, you would be using  `malloc(some_number*sizeof(char))`. Considering that char is one byte in your system by the above malloc you're saying "Ok ! I wish to allocate some_number of bytes to c". Hope this is clear. Now with char**c, you have a pointer to pointer to char. You need to `malloc` 2 times. First `c=malloc(some_number*sizeof(char*))` and then `*c=malloc(some_number*sizeof(char))`. I mentioned this the comment to your question. `char**` or `char*[]` is for  a reason, the arguments to main can only be strings.

Comment: @EnglishStudent62 : I just made an edit. Intially I put `char *words_array[argc];` . Unfortunately this is not possible because index of an array should be constant. In other words arrays can only initialized at compile time not  run time. We need to do it the `malloc` way.

Comment: @EnglishStudent62 : In my method, you don't need the second malloc ie `*words_array=malloc(some_number*sizeof(char))` because you are assigning it to another pointer inside the for-loop using `words_array[i]=argv[i]` . Hope you're with me.

Comment: Yes I understand the logic but my question still stands on how do I fix my issue with qsort though? Its giving me an error that words_array in the first parameter of qsort is undeclared?

Comment: See the documentation of [qsort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm).  `qsort(words_array, argc-1, sizeof(char *), string_cmp)` looks good @EnglishStudent62

Comment: @EnglishStudent62 : By the way remove that `p` stuff from the code. You may copy the clean code in paste-bin and give me the link

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your for-loop. You compare `*p` with `argc` which is meaningless. Replace the loop with standard counter `i`.

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
```

Please note that instead of `argc - 1` it should be used `argc`, and the loop should start start from 1 and not from 0.
In addition, in the loop you can use `argv[i]` instead of `*argv`